# Mysqli showing table content in one row and column name not retrieved from db

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was trying to use Mysqli instead of Mysql with php in order to gather contents from my database and the code below (code 1) works fine but i have 2 problems:

1 - The code 1 shows all the rows on the same line instead of one above each other.

2 - I cant get how to get the columns name of the table like when i was doing with mysql method (code 2).

---------------------code 1----------------

```
 <?php
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', '...');
    if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
    }
    $sql = <<<SQL SELECT * FROM `...`
    SQL;

    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<tr class='info'>
                    <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td> 
                    </tr>";     }    ?>
```

---------------- code 2------------

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
mysql_select_db('dhocp');    
$query = "SELECT * FROM ..."; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table class='table'>";
echo '<tr>';
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) { 
    echo "<th>".mysql_field_name($result, $i)."</th>"; 
}
echo '</tr>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
echo "<tr class='info'><td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>
               <td>" . $row['...'] . "</td>
               </tr>"; 
}
echo "</table>"; 
mysql_close(); 
?>
```

------------ fix update ------------------

addedd

```
  echo "<table class='table'>";
```

in code 1 before the while loop

------------ fix update 2 --------------Show column table----

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "...", "...", "...");

$query = "SELECT * from ...";

if ($result = $db->query($query)) {

    /* Get field information for all columns */
    while ($finfo = $result->fetch_field()) {
        printf("%s\n", $finfo->name);

    }
    $result->close();
}
```

Comment: code1 doesn't even have a table

Comment: I mean an html table !

Comment: yes i just copy and pasted my code and changed all the table names and other info, like column name with ...

Comment: Oh gotcha. That would be problem 1: everything being displayed on same line. and problem 2: use $result->fetch_fields

Comment: yes sorry i will update my question and figure out how to fix the problem 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could e.g. print the array keys (=field names) on the first iteration

```
$header = true;
foreach( $mysqli->query('SELECT id,x,y FROM soFoo') as $row ) {
    if ( $header ) {
        // on the first iteration print the array-keys <-> field names
        $header = false;
        echo '<tr><th>', join('</th><th>', array_map('htmlspecialchars', array_keys($row))), '</th></tr>', "\r\n";
    }
    echo '<tr><td>', join('</td><td>', array_map('htmlspecialchars', $row)), '</th></tr>', "\r\n";
}
```

or you fetch the metadata as descibed at http://docs.php.net/mysqli.quickstart.metadata

```
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT id,x,y FROM soFoo');
$meta = $result->fetch_fields();
echo '<tr><th>', join('</th><th>', array_map( function($e) { return htmlspecialchars($e->name); }, $meta)), '</th></tr>', "\r\n";

foreach( $result as $row ) {
    echo '<tr><td>', join('</td><td>', array_map('htmlspecialchars', $row)), '</th></tr>', "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Regarding the second code you posted I need to modify ('SELECT id,x,y FROM soFoo') , with [id,x,y] column name of my table and [soFoo] as my table name?

Comment: Or you change the name of the table so `soFoo` and the names of your fields to id,x, and y ;-)

Comment: ok because thats what I did but i get 2 error in the same line 1) Undefined variable: mysqli in .... and Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in ...

Comment: I was able to retrieve the name of the column table and show it on the top of the table rows (as i posted in update fix2 above in my question), but i only get the list of the column table in a row and not each column name on the top of the column table. Any advice?